# Render checkboxes with subcategories on change of category drop down in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a newbie problem here :)

I want my items to have a single main category (done) and one or many subcategories. I have two models - one for the main category and one for the subcategories. When creating a new item I want to be able to dynamically change the checkboxes for my subcategories.

I have almost achieved what I want with jQuery and a request to a view that shows the checkboxes. My only problem right now is that when I try to create a new item and I submit an invalid form when I do render 'new' the subcategories that have been checked are gone.

Here are some bits of my code:

This is from my controller:

```
def subcategories 
    @subcategories = Category.find(params[:id]).subcategories
    if !params[:item_id].nil?
        @item = Item.find(params[:item_id])
    else
        @item = Item.new
    end
    render :partial => "subcategories"
end
```

This is my view:

```
<% if !@subcategories.blank? %>
  <% @subcategories.each do |subcat| %> 
    <%= label_tag dom_id(subcat), subcat.name, :class => "checkbox" do %>
        <%= check_box_tag "item[subcategory_ids][]", subcat.id, @item.subcategory_ids.include?(subcat.id) , id: dom_id(subcat) %> <%= subcat.name %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And this is my new.html.erb:

```
<div id="subcategories_main">
    <%= label_tag "Subcategories" %>
    <div id="subcategories">
    </div>
  </div>
```

And I have this small JavaScript to show the checkboxes:

```
$("#item_category_id").change(function() {
// make a POST call and replace the content
var category_id = $('select#item_category_id :selected').val();
if(category_id != "" || category_id != "0") 
{
  $.get('/categories/' + category_id + '/subcategories', function(data){
      $("#subcategories").html(data);
  })
}
});
```

Comment: They are supposed to be gone rt? Anyway can you give more code? The entire view and everything.. whats the "item_cateogry_id"? Where is that in the view?? post everything..

Answer (score 0):

Form submission refreshes the page and so checkboxes will definitely get cleared out.

You can do two things at this point:

1. Do Form validation at Client side. And hence you will never submit an invalid form.
2. Or create another global list in controller before  `render "new"` that contains the checked subcategories (coming from params). Something like :

   ```
   @checked_subcategories = params[:sub_categories]
   ```

   And then you can check in the view while iterating, like `if @checked_subcategories.include?(name)`, mark checkbox as checked.